# sudo with Kerberos credentials

Tags: linux, kerberos, sudo, mitkerberos

We are on Oracle Linux 7.9, which is part of a Kerberos realm.

I would like account `foo` to be able to execute (without any password) *one command* as account `bar` with Kerberos credentials of `bar` acquired, but without giving `foo` shell access, to fully impersonate account `bar` in an interactive session.

How could I achieve this in a properly? One option I see her is having

1. a wrapper script that executes the desired command after performing a kinit from a keytab file of `bar` and
2. a sudo rule that allows executing the wrapper script to `foo`.

This approach does not seem to be great to me. What would be a proper solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the command with `sudo` or similar is actually a fairly good approach – it provides UID-based separation to prevent the invoker from accessing the temporary tickets.

You could avoid the need for a wrapper script by using either gss-proxy or KRB5_CLIENT_KEYTAB to have libkrb5 automatically acquire tickets on behalf of the user (or by having a cronjob to acquire them with kinit), but otherwise it's going to have to function the same way as you described.

Alternatively, you could keep the wrapper script and have it *sudo itself* if needed. That is, if `/usr/local/bin/cmdbar` is invoked as any other user than 'bar' it would `sudo -u bar` itself, and the invoker wouldn't need to worry about that.

```bash
if [ "$(whoami)" != bar ]; then
    exec sudo -u bar -- "$0" "$@" || exit
fi
```

---

If it is critical that *not even 'bar'* has access to the keytab (e.g. if the command being run is one that gives unlimited file access, there are a few options:

- Use gssproxy (if the command uses standard system libkrb5). The keytab will only need to be accessible by gssproxy while the command's libkrb5 library will ask gssproxy to do all Kerberos operations, similar to the way ssh-agent works. This raises the bar from "read the ticket file" to "talk to gssproxy via socket".
- Use a yet another account to `sudo -u ... kinit`, specifying *only* the necessary service principal (not the krbtgt!), then sudo-chown the resulting ticket cache to `bar`.
- Probably, some form of "constrained delegation" where gssproxy can use its machine keytab to impersonate `bar` and acquire service tickets in a limited way. (The gssproxy docs have an example for doing this with NFS.)

Comment: I have to avoid granting access to the Keytab file itself, as this is a Hadoop cluster, where we cannot allow foo to impersonate bar when talking to Hadoop services. The closest thing I could come up with was self-sudo in the script, which I do not really like either.

I am not sure we can install gssproxy; so I would be looking for a solution I can implement with scripts and standard utilities.

Comment: Doesn't regular sudo with a wrapper script already achieve that, though? The invoker cannot read the keytab directly, only run specific commands that will use it. But if you also have a requirement that even those commands wouldn't have access to the keytab directly either, then gssproxy or a *second* level of sudo would be necessary.

Comment: The wrapper script does work, but I find that somewhat dodgy. I will look into gssproxy.